# Error: Could not open file when loading 3D model in AR mode using Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, augmented-reality

Error in calling object from database and showing in AR mode

The access token and path are the same, I have added debugs but it is showing up to loadModel Finished. When loading a 3D model, the inscription "Could not open file" appears.

All permissions are added, the camera is turned on, the 3d model has the same path in the database and in Storage. I published an article in which there is a 3d model, now I need to call it and show it in augmented reality mode. What could be the problem?

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    typealias UIViewType = ARSCNView
    @Binding var isModelLoaded: Bool
    
    let arView = ARSCNView()
    
    // Firebase Storage reference
    let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
    
    // Firebase Realtime Database reference
    let database = Database.database().reference()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARSCNView {
        let arView = ARSCNView()
        let scene = SCNScene()
        arView.scene = scene
        arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator // Добавляем делегата AR сессии
        
        // Создаем конфигурацию AR сессии
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical] // Разрешаем обнаружение горизонтальных и вертикальных поверхностей
        configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic // Включаем автоматическую обработку текстур
        configuration.isAutoFocusEnabled = true // Включаем автоматическую фокусировку камеры
        
        arView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors]) // Запускаем AR сессию
        
        loadModel(arView)
        print("loadModel called")
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARSCNView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    func loadModel(_ arView: ARSCNView) {
        // Получаем ID статьи из Firebase Realtime Database
        database.child("article").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            guard let articles = snapshot.value as? [String: [String: Any]] else {
                print("Cannot get articles from snapshot value")
                return
            }
            guard let articleID = articles.keys.first else {
                print("Cannot get article ID")
                return
            }
            
            // Создаем путь к модели
            let modelPath = "article_models/\(articleID).usdz"
            // Загружаем модель из Firebase Storage
            let modelRef = storage.child(modelPath)
            modelRef.downloadURL(completion: { url, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Cannot get download URL: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                guard let url = url else {
                    print("Cannot get download URL")
                    return
                }
                print("Model download URL: \(url)")
                let scene = try? SCNScene(url: url, options: nil)
                guard let scene = scene else {
                    print("Cannot load scene from URL")
                    return
                }
                print("Scene loaded")
                // Создаем SCNNode из загруженной модели
                let node = SCNNode()
                for childNode in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
                    node.addChildNode(childNode)
                }
                // Устанавливаем позицию и масштаб модели
                node.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.5)
                node.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.1, y: 0.1, z: 0.1)
                // Добавляем SCNNode в AR-сцену
                arView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
                print("Node added to scene")
                // Устанавливаем isModelLoaded в true
                self.isModelLoaded = true
                print("loadModel finished")
            })
        })
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {
        
        let parent: ARViewContainer
        
        init(_ parent: ARViewContainer) {
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()
            parent.arView.delegate = self
            parent.arView.session.delegate = self
            
            // Создаем конфигурацию AR сессии
            let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
            configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical] // Разрешаем обнаружение горизонтальных и вертикальных поверхностей
            configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic // Включаем автоматическую обработку текстур
            configuration.isAutoFocusEnabled = true // Включаем автоматическую фокусировку камеры
            
            parent.arView.session.run(configuration) // Запускаем AR сессию
        }
        
        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
            // Если добавляемый якорь - горизонтальная плоскость, то размещаем на ней 3D-модель
            if let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {
                let modelNode = parent.arView.scene.rootNode.clone()
                node.addChildNode(modelNode)
                modelNode.position = SCNVector3(planeAnchor.center.x, 0, planeAnchor.center.z)
            }
        }
    }
}
```